# Openvpn: Server cannot ping a client which ignore redirect-gateway

Tags: routes, ping, gateway, openvpn

I'm having a problem pinging from my vpn server to a client (and not the other way).

I have an **openvpn server**: **10.8.0.1/16**.

I have a **client 1** where all traffic is routed through the VPN: 10.8.1.9/16. No problem with this client 1: **everything works**.

I have a **client 2** (**10.8.1.3/16**)where I would like traffic not to be routed through the VPN but the machines to be accessible.
This client 2, 10.8.1.3, can ping the server -> 10.8.0.1 ping ok.
But, **the server cannot ping client 2... :(**

I've been looking for 2 days and despite reading documentation and other posts, I can't find it.

Anyone have an idea?

Here my configuration.
Server:

```
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
    dev tun
    topology subnet
    cipher AES-256-GCM
    auth SHA256
    verb 3
    # keys here
    # ...
    ###
    key-direction 0
    keepalive 10 60
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    proto udp
    # Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
    port 1194
    dev tun0
    status /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
    user nobody
    group nogroup
    #comp-lzo no
    ### Route Configurations Below
    ### Push Configurations Below
    push "block-outside-dns"
    push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 172.8.0.1"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
    # Pour indiquer le chemin des fichiers config des clients
    client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
    # Pour interdire la connexion de client sans fichier config
    ccd-exclusive
    # Pour autoriser openvpn-monitor
    management 0.0.0.0 5555
    ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
    explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Route table:

```
default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens192
10.8.0.0/16 via 172.8.0.2 dev br-2222222222
10.255.255.1 dev ens192 scope link
172.8.0.0/24 dev br-2222222222 proto kernel scope link src 172.8.0.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

As you can see in this route table, the VPN traffic (10.8.0.0/16) is routed via 172.8.0.2. In fact, my openvpn run on docker.

My client 2 (10.8.1.3) VPN config:

```
    client
    nobind
    dev tun
    remote-cert-tls server
    cipher AES-256-GCM
    auth SHA256
    remote my-server-vpn.com 1194 udp
    key-direction 1
    # To not consider the server redirect-gateway in order to avoid all traffic through VPN Gateway
    pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway"
```

Route table client 2 (10.8.1.3) (when client vpn is running) :

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.3 metric 100
10.8.0.0/16 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.3
<my-server-vpn-ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-1111111111 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 100
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 100
```

Ping from 10.8.1.3 to 10.8.0.1 OK
Ping from 10.8.0.1 to 10.8.1.3 KO

I hope someone could help me

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
# From my client2, to see the ping request
tcpdump icmp
# From my server, exec the ping
ping 10.8.1.3
```

On my client2, this command tells me that the ping arrives with the address 172.8.0.1. So, I have added the following line in the client2 config file:

```
route 172.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

This solve my problem and now I can ping the client2 from the server.